# What is the iOS API to see when the running app was installed from the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, installed-applications

I want to know when to warn and cripple after the free trial period.  Thanks.

Comment: You can save a trial end date in keychain on first launch. The only way to clear this would be for the user to erase their device. But, how do they continue to use the app after the trial period? If it is a one off purchase, then it would be more appropriate to use IAP to start the trial as Apple requires - https://indiespark.top/business/free-trial-app-store/. If it is a subscription app then you should use a free trial in your subscription IAP

Comment: The original purchase date for the app is available in the app receipt.

Comment: Thanks. I want the app to be fully functional after free installation, no further action required. After the free trial period, one desirable function would be disabled pending auto-renewing subscription.